# java- find minimum/maximum in an entered set of numbers

Tags: java, max, minimum

Using the while loop, I have to do the following:
Use a variable "i," which counts how many integers were entered, a variable "number," which spits out the number entered, a variable "min," which indicates the smallest number entered so far, and a variable "max," which indicates the largest number entered so far.
The user will enter a total of 5 integers.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMax
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   int i = 1;

   while (i <= 5)
   {
    int smallest = 0;
    int largest = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Amount of numbers entered: " + i);

    System.out.println("Number entered: " + number);

    if (number < min)
    {
      min = number;
    }
    System.out.println("Smallest # so far: " + min);

    if (number > max)
    {
      max = number;
    }
    System.out.println("Largest # so far: " + max);


    i++;

   }
 }
}
```

When I run this, the "i," "number," and "maximum" variables all seem to work properly. However, the "minimum" variable keeps in mind that the set number of "minimum" is 0. Is there a way to fix this, so that if I enter the number 10 for the first number and the number 2 for the second number, the code will spit out "2" as the minimum instead of "0"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

So when you are looking for the smallest number, it will compare maximum integer value with current element - which is definitely smaller or equal. So smallest will be either correct or it will be updated. Analogically for maximum.

And by the way, these two have to be declared outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to move `min` and `max` variables out of the loop.

Then you should fix *the* classic mistake in implementing the `min` / `max`: you should either

- Start `min` at `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `max` at `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, or
- Start both `min` and `max` at the first value entered.

I prefer the second approach, because it keeps explicit initialization out of the code:

```
int min = 0, max = 0, i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    System.out.println("Enter number: "+(i+1));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (i == 0) {
        min = max = input;
    } else {
        ... // Do the conditions to determine if input is a new min or a max
    }
}
```